# Proof with supremum

Tags: random-variables, supremum-and-infimum

Let $|X_n|$ < Y a.s., each n, n = 1,2,3..

How could I prove that also $sup_n|X_n|\le Y$ a.s?

---

How does the proof change if I now that $lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = X$ a.s. and that |X| $ < \infty$? specifically, what I want to prove is now that $sup_n|X_n|<\infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean $|X_n|\leq Y$ almost surely, not $X_n\leq Y$. (otherwise the statement is obviously false. You need either absolute value at both places or in none of them)

Well, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $P(|X_n|\leq Y)=1$. A countable intersection of events with probability $1$ is also an event with probability $1$, hence:

$1=P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty\{ |X_n|\leq Y\})=P(|X_n|\leq Y\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N})=P(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |X_n|\leq Y)$

Comment: That's true! thank you also for the initial observation, was obviously right.

Comment: I edited the question since the problem it seems to me related. Give a look if it may concert to you

Comment: Well, let's assume the random variables $X_n$ are finite. Then as we know a convergent sequence of real numbers is bounded. So if $P(X_n\to X)=1$ then $P(\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |X_n|<\infty)=1$. This simply follows from monotonicity of probability measure. At each point where $X_n$ converges to a finite value it is bounded.